# excel is taking mysql date format as text format

Tags: mysql, excel, date

we are trying to write formulas with mysql date format. we exported mysql dates. we are getting date formats `mm/dd/yy` format. But excel taking it as `TEXT` format.

In mysql we tried to approaches.

first one is `DATE_FORMAT` like below

```
DATE_FORMAT(column_name, "%c/%e/%y")
```

second one is `FROM_UNIXTIMESTAMP`

```
FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(pa.value),'%c/%e/%y')
```

for first one it is recognizing as `TEXT` format
for second one it is recognizing as `DATE` format. But again we have to click on the column's manually. After selecting/clicking on the columns then `excel` taking them as date.

are there any suggestions/solutions for the problem?
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Workbench [has a wizard to automate this](https://www.mysql.com/why-mysql/windows/excel/import/), assuming you have access to Workbench.

Comment: We are able to export the data. but problem is it is taking date format as TEXT format in excel.

Comment: Not entirely familiar, but, in general, Excel will interpret a "date" correctly if and only if either the format is unambiguous (eg. yyyy-mm-dd) or if the incoming format matches the Windows Regional Short Date format.  If the format is ambiguous and does NOT match the Short Date format, it will interpret some as a date (usually incorrectly) and others as text.

Comment: It is working fine when we click on the column and change it to date format. But directly it is not recognizing. We have to go and change it to date format manually everytime.

Answer (score 1):

`CAST(date_columb AS DATE)` this working super fine :)